# MATLAB - passing new value of parameter from GUI into .m script

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I want to make simple GUI for my script, where I can edit parameter values and running that script.

I've created example scipt and GUI with 2 buttons. I'cant put script code into GUI code, I will need to aply it on much larger script.

So, script code:

```
number = 10;
variable(1:10) = NaN;

for i = 1:10;
    variable(i) = i * number;
end

figure
plot(variable)
```

Push button code, that is working fine. script is name of .m file, not function:

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
evalin('base','script')
```

But I dont know what to type into edit button code If i want to change value of "number" in the script:

```
function edit1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to edit1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of edit1 as text
%        str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of edit1 as a double
```

And last thing, sometimes when I try to plot more graphs, one figure overwrites GUI figure and I can see only buttons, but not whole GUI.

Thank you fot any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hint given in the last piece of code is enough.

```
a = str2double(get(hObject,'String'));
```

This will save the input value as a `double`, in the callback function's stack.

In order to pass this value to the caller script's (base) stack, use [`assignin`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/assignin.html)

```
assignin('base', 'number', a)
```

Comment: Ok, that was easy, thank you! Can you please tell me, how to avoid replacing of GUI interace with boxplot graph? After using GUI I can see only buttons like this:
http://imgur.com/a/j2Zun

Comment: how about draw the box plot in a new figure?

Comment: Jesus I'am dumb. Every other plot is in new figure just this one not.
Ok, that's probably all, thank you.